# Battery not detected

Tags: battery

As the title say my laptop battery is not detected in maverick.
I'm using ubuntu since ever and I've never come across this problem.
I have a msi ms-171f vr705 series and everything is working fine except for the battery.

```
cat: /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/info: No such device
```

Comment: acpi does not work for some users. there is a workaround : use a command line http://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal

Answer (score 6):

Usually the Laptop battery is labelled `BAT0`. Have you tried running:

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info
```

Also have you tried adding `acpi=force` onto your GRUB command line?

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Go to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`
3. Replace it with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"`
4. Save your changes.
5. Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

(If there is something already within the `""` at Step 2 just add a space after it and add `acpi=force`)

Comment: thank you no there is no BAT0 i've always had BAT1 i think the laptop is able to include two batteries via usb or i don't know anyway i'll try to add acpi=force to grub and see how it goes..

Comment: OK I forgot to add after you make the update run sudo update-grub afterwards

Comment: i tried acpi=force and it didn't fix the problem..i'll apply all the updates and see what happens any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a bit old, but someone may benefit from my reply. The problem is caused by an upstream kernel bug.  You can view the bug report here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24002.  The last version of Ubuntu with a kernel that showed battery information from a MS-171F laptop motherboard was 9.10 (Karmic).  Unfortunately, Karmic reached its end of life date in April.  Hopefully they will have the problem resolved soon and it will filter down to us in an update.

Comment: actually i didn't have the problem until maverick (it was detected in lucid) anyway i'm still waiting for a fix ....

Answer (score 1):

in my case, this happen often after I upgrade kernel and I don't reboot as often as suggested.

after I rebooted, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
Find the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
Replace it with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noacpi"
Save your changes.
Run sudo update-grub and reboot.

If it doesn't work and you have external graphics like nvdia, then update and make latest version of the driver as default and then check. I have a MSI GF-63 and it worked.

Comment: are you sure disabling ACPI is a good idea? After all, the battery shows up under /proc/acpi ?!?