# My TOSHIBA L655 S5144 Battery is not Detected on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: kernel, laptop, 12.10, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Battery not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7485/battery-not-detected)

i used toshiba l655 S5144 and when i installed Ubuntu 12.10 gnome "no battery" present