# Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize my battery

Tags: 14.04, laptop, power-management, battery, acpi

For the last 3 years I've been using a Samsung notebook. I was using Ubuntu 13.10 until 2 weeks ago. Then I decided to format and install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Everything was working great, until the third day, when I did not do anything else than installing the software updates, I noticed my battery was not being recognized. The battery indicator shows `charging`, and when I click it it just says `Battery`. The day started to malfunction just said `unknown battery`, and when I unplugged my laptop it shut down.

If a try to turn on my laptop with the battery in and not plugged into an AC adapter, it does not turn on: it only works when its plugged in. Also, when its plugged in with the battery the light showing the battery status is now always switching from green to red (which it never did before).

I guessed it was just my battery dieing, so I tried in another notebook like mine and was working perfectly, full battery, 3 hrs and a half running. How can I get Ubuntu to recognize my battery? I really don't want a laptop that is a portable PC, I need a portable laptop again.

Comment: Ahh...am I missing something here?  You have one of the following problems: (1) battery is dead and cannot be recharged - replace battery, (2) your charger is no longer working and battery is not recharged - replace the charger, (3) the battery in question is not the vendor choice and thus may no longer be meeting all the specifications the vendor requires, (4) mating problem inside the laptop where the battery is no longer making proper contact.

Comment: Please add the vendor and model number of the two laptops in question, additionally the battery information (vendor, cells, ....)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem for ASUS Zenbook and resolved with:

edit grub:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

change like below:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1"
```

update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and restart

Comment: Mind explaining what all this is, and what part specifically fixed the problem, before I blindly type it into my boot loader config?  I need 125 points to downvote, but consider this a virtual downvote

Comment: I agree, never just blindly copy and paste code from the internet.. Always explain the usage of the copy and highlight extracts of changes. My guess while im still new to searching for my answer would be `acpi=force pcie_aspm=force` are the two of interest... Similar post with more of an answer = http://askubuntu.com/questions/7485/battery-not-detected

Answer (score -1):

Something like this happened to me when I replaced the internal battery in my Dell XPS14 laptop with one direct from Dell, spec'd for this laptop. There was no indicator icon, and `cat /proc/acpi/battery/bat0/info` or whatever the path is simply reported that no battery was present. After trying a few different simple solutions suggested by google without success,  I booted back up and found that `cat`ing the same file now gave useful info. I purged and reinstalled `indicator-power`, rebooted, and the indicator was back.

My only explanation is that, with the battery actually  being new and not refurbished, it needed a few minutes of charging to gather history and start reporting statistics to the OS. I realize this probably doesn't apply to your situation, so feel free to ignore this answer, but I think this might be a useful perspective for other Googlers of "ubuntu does not recognize new battery", like myself.